# Why can I access foreach variable outside of its scope?

Tags: php

I noticed that I can access the value of the variable `$order` outside of its scope.

```
public function dryRunAction()
{     
    $allCustomersBefore = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->getCollection()
                                                       ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                                                       ->addFieldToFilter('customer_activated', '1')
                                                       ->addFieldToFilter('group_id', array('6'));
    

    foreach($allCustomersBefore as $customer) {

        $orders = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_collection')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->addFieldToFilter('customer_id', $customer->getId());

        $atLeastOnePendingOrder = false;
        foreach($orders as $order) {
                    
            if ($order->getStatus() == 'pending') {
                $atLeastOnePendingOrder = true;
                break;
            }
        }


        if ($atLeastOnePendingOrder) {
            echo $customer->getName() . " already made an order (Order Status: ". $order->getStatus() . ").<br>";        
        }
    }
}
```

The output is `Mr Sample Customer already made an order (Order Status: pending).`

Comment: because the code is synchronous it takes the last iteration of the definition inside the loop ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The foreach loop is a block level, not a function level.

Variables declared in function are not available outside.

But, variables outside block are always available.

Their values should be the latest value from iteration.

[Reference:](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)